# Convert LINQ query to SQL query

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I was trying to create a stored procedure equivalent to the linq query attached below. And I want to call that stored procedure from my repository where this code was running.

Here is the Linq query:

```
var rates = _dbcontext.tableName
            .Where(x => x.Param1 == param1 && x.Param2 == param2 && x.Param3 == param3)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Orderby(x => x.Weight)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why would you want to convert it to SQL?

Comment: @ChristianBaumann I have query a large dataset (200,000 records) and improve the efficiency, i have indexed the table. That's why i am trying different approaches as well as looking into stored procedures.

Comment: 200K rows is not large IMHO, and since you have the proper indexes it should run fast. EF has some overhead, right, but not sure if it is worth the effort converting this particular one. And when you need it, you can still execute raw SQL queries with Linq To EF (or SQL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(it didn't allow me to put this in comments)

```
select * 
from tableName 
where Param1 = @param1 and 
       Param2 = @param2 and 
       Param3 = @param3 
order by weight;
```

EDIT: Full stored procedure creation code (Data types are fictionary):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure
    @param1 NVARCHAR(20),
    @param2 DATETIME,
    @param3 INT
AS
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE Param1 = @param1
      AND Param2 = @param2
      AND Param3 = @param3
ORDER BY weight;
```

And also, it could instead be a TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_MyFunction
(
    @param1 NVARCHAR(20),
    @param2 DATETIME,
    @param3 INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tableName
    WHERE Param1 = @param1
          AND Param2 = @param2
          AND Param3 = @param3
);
```

Note that TVF variation doesn't have an "Order By" BUT it could be used in another select for example:

```
Select * 
from dbo.udf_MyFunction(N'Par1', '20210101', 5)
order by weight;
```

Comment: sorry didn't work

Comment: @ShakerKamal, What didn't work? I naturally don't know your real field names. Also did you define those parameters?

Comment: How should they define these parameters? And how will they be effective? We only see a tiny code snippet without any context.

Comment: @GertArnold, check the documentation for creating any stored procedure for MS SQL Server. Here it was sufficient to provide the select body as the OP sounded to know how to create an SP already. It is simply something like Create Procedure MyProcedure @ param1 nvarchar(10), @ param2 int, ... as select * 
from tableName 
where Param1 = @ param1 and 
       Param2 = @ param2 and 
       Param3 = @ param3 
order by weight;

Comment: @GertArnold and BTW you could also create a TVF instead (Table Valued Function). Those parameters would be function paramaters and the function body would simply be that select.

Comment: @GertArnold, I updated my reply to include SP and TVF samples.

Comment: Now *that's* a Stack Overflow answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have up to now used LinqPad (https://www.linqpad.net/), written my query and had it immediately translated in SQL. Works like a charm!

Comment: Hi, currently i am using Mac, couldn't find any mac version of linqpad

Comment: @ShakerKamal, I too use a Mac and I still love linqpad (a registered user really). I use LinqPad in windows (virtual through parallels - actually it is my daily production environment). For Mac, you might try rosylnpad (I didn't try and don't know how it compares to LinqPad).